# Hide div with jQuery from called AJAX page (ADVANCED?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

1: I have a page that shows four Google Pie Charts. I have clickable tabs to show each one of them.

2: However, I hide 3 out of 4 of them att all times with jQuery hide/show but on page load they are all visible until I click one of my tabs. See picture below.

[image]

2.1: The selected tab is marked with a red underline. As you can see, I have four tabs, each for a matching chart.

3: When a date is selected in the boxes on the top of the picture, the form is POSTED, with AJAX, using this code below.

3.1:

```
        <form method="post" action="~/AJAXcalls/repinintAJAX.cshtml" name="form">
            <div class="reportDateDiv">

                <a class="blackColor fSize18 RPtxt">Reporting Period</a>

                <input type="text" name="inputDate" spellcheck="false" class="datepicker metricDateTextbox capitalFirst"
                      onchange="mySubmit(this.form)" value="@inputDate" autocomplete="off" placeholder="@placeholderStartDate.ToString("MMM d, yyyy")" readonly="readonly" />

                <a class="blackColor fSize16 RPtxtTo">to</a>

                <input type="text" name="endDate" spellcheck="false" class="datepicker metricDateTextbox capitalFirst"
                      onchange="mySubmit(this.form)" value="@endDate" autocomplete="off" placeholder="@noEndDate.ToString("MMM d, yyyy")" readonly="readonly" />

                <select name="NormOrAvg" class="dwmViewSelect" onchange="mySubmit(this.form)">
                    <option selected=@(Request.Form["NormOrAvg"] == "1") value="1">Rep Per Set</option>
                    <option selected=@(Request.Form["NormOrAvg"] == "2") value="2">Average Rep Per Set</option>
                </select>
                </div>
        </form>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function mySubmit(theForm) {
                $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
                    data: $(theForm).serialize(), // get the form data
                    type: $(theForm).attr('method'), // GET or POST
                    url: $(theForm).attr('action'), // the file to call
                    success: function (response) { // on success..
                        $('#here').html(response); // update the DIV
                    }

                });
            }
        </script>
```

4. What I want is for 3 of the 4 divs containing the charts to be hidden from the beginning when the form is posted so that they all dont appear. At the moment they will all show until I click one of the tabs, only then do they appear leaving only the correct one showing.

5: I tried to solve this with jQuery to add/remove a class that was `display: none;` but that gave me this error showing in the picture below.

[image]

5.1: I believe this error appears because these 4 divs I'm trying to hide is on the ajax page which is called on post. 
This error only appears on the divs I put my display none class on, as you can see in the picture the deadlift tab is selected, so if I put the class on the last 3 divs, only the first one works.

6: This is my 4 divs that the chart data is loaded into.

```
<div id="piechart" class="repPieChart"></div>                
<div id="piechartS" class="repPieChart"></div>
<div id="piechartB" class="repPieChart"></div>
<div id="piechartD" class="repPieChart"></div>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you please ask a clear question? Your question is quite unclear at the moment. Consider creating a [mcve] of your problem.

Comment: okey, so basically I have 4 divs, I want three of them to already be hidden on page load, but I get errors because these divs are on a separate page and called via ajax @AndreiGheorghiu

Comment: Ok, i'll do my best to create a better question.

Comment: Done, updated my entire post! @AndreiGheorghiu

Answer (score 1):

I'd do this with CSS over Javascript.

```
#here > div {
  display: none;
}
#here > div.piechart {
  display: block;
}
```

The jQuery `.show()` will work on these already hidden `div`s.

Comment: to clarify, I have 4 tabs for each div, (total, squat, benchpress, deadlift) and I only want "total" to be visible from the beginning.

Comment: I have edited my answer to have `.piechart` still visible.

Comment: Are you using a library to render those pie charts? Some Javascript libraries take issue with attempts to render when hidden. Perhaps render when switching the tabs?

Comment: how would one do that? switching tabs is just hide/show jQuery code

Comment: After the `.show()` line, call Google Charts' `.draw()` function.

Comment: var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));


                        chart.draw(data, options);

Comment: thats the draw stuff, simply just .hide().draw(data, options); ?

Comment: Not exactly. When clicking the tabs, on a line after you run your `.hide()` and `.show()` calls that is where your chart code should go. Show the parent `div` **then** draw the chart, each time the tab is changed.

Comment: can't say that I fully understand, but the chart is drawn on the called ajax page, is it still possible to call the draw thing on the first page with the tabs?

Comment: I had a feeling that was the case. If you set `visibility: hidden;` instead of `display: none;` then it shouldn't upset Google Charts, but you'd probably have to tinker with your CSS. Frankly, the best way to do this is to rethink your code and render the pie charts one at a time, at the moment the tab is made visible.

Comment: hehe that ended up being pretty weird, but thanks anyway, I now know that it wasn't because of AJAX but because of the google chart! I'll have to look up how this can be solved!